# En un TAD Lista en C++ ¿Qué diferencia existe entre el tamaño y la longitud de la lista?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo un TAD Lista en C++ pero con una implementación vectorial pseudoestática.
Aquí puedes ver la interfaz y el constructor de las dudas que tengo tanto al inicializar la lista como en su parte privada:

```
template <typename T>
class Lista
{
public:
 typedef int posicion;
 explicit Lista(size_t TamaMax); // Constructor
 Lista(const Lista<T> l); //Constructor de copia
 void insertar(const T& x, posicion p);
 ..
 .
private:
 T *elementos; //Puntero que apunta para crear un vector de elementos
 int Lmax; //Tamaño del vector
 int n; //Longitud de la lista
};

template <typename T>
inline Lista<T>::Lista(size_t TamaMax): elementos(new T[TamaMax]), Lmax(TamaMax), n(0) {}
```

La cuestión es que yo sé que la forma de crear una lista de forma vectorial es que cada elemento estará en una posición del vector (en un índice del vector).

Pero lo que no entiendo es ¿qué significa realmente Lmax y qué significa n en su parte privada?

¿Alguien puede aclarármelo con un ejemplo?

Gracias!

Comment: `Lista(const Lista<T> l)` - NO funcionará. El constructor de copia debe utilizar pase por referencia. `Lista(const Lista<T>& l)` está bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los comentarios de las variables-miembro son bastante explicativos:

```
T *elementos; //Puntero que apunta para crear un vector de elementos
int Lmax; //Tamaño del vector
int n; //Longitud de la lista
```

Mirando la lista de inicialización del constructor

```
elementos(new T[TamaMax])
Lmax(TamaMax)
n(0)
```

podemos concluir:

- `elementos`: puntero a la zona de memoria en la que se colocan los elementos. Reservada con `new` en el constructor.
- `n`: número de elementos **actualmente almacenados**. Aunque la memoria está ya reservada con anterioridad, de algún modo tenemos que saber **cuantos elementos** se han colocado en la lista. Ese contador de elementos es `n`.
- `Lmax`: número de elementos **para los que se ha reservado espacio**. También puede verse como **número máximo de elementos que es posible almacenar**. Si en algún momento `n == Lmax`, la cola **estaría llena** y no sería posible almacenar mas elementos.

La variable miembro `n` cambia con cada inserción / extracción, de forma que siempre contiene el número de elementos efectivamente almacenados.

Sin el código de `insertar( )`, y solo con los datos que tenemos, no podemos saber si la lista es estática (el máximo número de elementos se fija en el constructor) o dinámica (el tamaño de la memoria utilizada por `elementos` cambia según sea necesario).